# Practise driving in the UK as a learner

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, driving

I recently took my driving test and failed on a very silly mistake.

I was thinking about it and the only way to get around that is the drive more often on the road. My instructor has only a fixed pre-defined slot for further lessons, but I would really like to drive more often than that.

Is there any way I can get this going without the instructor?

As an expat who has recently moved to the UK, I know no one with a driving license for 3 years and who would accompany me when I drive. This is really causing a hard time where I live.

I am willing to buy the insurance and car (I will need one anyway), but need a license which means more practise.

Answer (score 3):

You will find it hard (but not impossible) to get a vehicle insured as a learner driver (provisional licence) especially without a specific named driver.

If you can find someone to supervise your driving, you can hire dual-control cars for driving lessons from some of the car hire places, with the appropriate insurance included for you as a provisional driver.

https://www.arnoldclarkrental.com/dual-control-hire  from £12 an hour.

If you are found driving as a learner driver in an uninsured vehicle (which includes a vehicle insured for a fully-licenced driver but driven by a provisional driver not insured for it), it's a minimum of fixed penalty of £300 and 6 penalty points, with an unlimited fine and disqualification if it goes to court. The police can also seize and destroy the vehicle, even if it's not yours. The maximum penalty upon conviction of driving otherwise in accordance with a driving licence (including failing to display L plates, or a provisional licenceholder not having a supervisor) is a fine not exceeding Level 3 (£1,000) and the endorsement of 3 - 6 penalty points. The court has disqualification as an option.

I mention this because as a recent arrival in this country you might not be aware that the police and courts prosecute these offences rigorously.

Comment: Thanks! The whole point of this post was to find the 'right' way to do this; I absolutely do not want loopholes or illegal ways to be on the road!

Answer (score 2):

My advice is go for a professional service, because a good instructor will be able to help you identify your weaknesses and focus on them. There are plenty of driving schools and independent instructors all over the country, and there are many websites or social media profiles with plenty of feedback. Typically they offer better deals if you book 10 or more driving lessons, but you can find instructors that you can book for fewer hours if needed.

Comment: I have already done this! I just want more time behind the wheel quickly, but my instructor is all booked up :)

Comment: @krish7919 Then book a *different* instructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the money and time available I would consider taking an intensive driving course. You should be able to find one lasting a day, or one or two weeks, depending on your budget and how much practice you need.

https://www.rac.co.uk/drive/advice/learning-to-drive/intensive-driving-courses/